# Hive Where Clause 'And'/'Or' Order of Operations

Tags: hive, hiveql, where-clause

I'm using Hadoop 2.7.3. When you run a hiveql command and have a where clause with 'and' and 'or' in it how does it distribute the conditions?

For example
Say I have the following query:

```
... where A and B or C and D.
```

Does it return one of the following:

```
A or B or C or D
((A and B) or C) and D
(A and B and D) or C
A and (B or C) and D
```

I know I can use parentheses  to specifc exactly which of the above is used, but what does it do by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer by @GordonLinoff is correct. You can verify this by constructing the truth table using the following query:

```sql
SELECT *, A and B or C and D AS result
FROM
  (SELECT TRUE AS a
   UNION ALL SELECT FALSE AS a) A
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT TRUE AS b
   UNION ALL SELECT FALSE AS b) B
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT TRUE AS c
   UNION ALL SELECT FALSE AS c) C
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT TRUE AS d
   UNION ALL SELECT FALSE AS d) D
```

Which ooutputs:

```sql
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
|  a.a|  b.b|  c.c|  d.d| result|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
| true| true| true|false|   true|
| true| true| true| true|   true|
| true| true|false|false|   true|
| true| true|false| true|   true|
|false| true| true|false|  false|
|false| true| true| true|   true|
|false| true|false|false|  false|
|false| true|false| true|  false|
| true|false| true|false|  false|
| true|false| true| true|   true|
| true|false|false|false|  false|
| true|false|false| true|  false|
|false|false| true|false|  false|
|false|false| true| true|   true|
|false|false|false|false|  false|
|false|false|false| true|  false|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
```

Thus, we can empirically conclude that this indeed evaluates to `(A and B) or (C and D)`.

Answer (score 4):

This is the precedence of operations.  `AND` binds more closely than `OR`, so:

```
A and B or C and D
```

is interpreted as:

```
(A and B) or (C and D)
```